# Angular: Place 'modal' element over clicked element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**What I'm trying to do**: I have two sibling directives.  When you click on an element in directive 1, it causes the other to show up over it, acting like a picker.

**The problem**: The code to do this looks really ugly. Specifically I am doing the following in the event handler in directive 2:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            $rootScope.$on('show-thing2', function(event, data){
                el[0].setAttribute('style', 'left:' + (data.left-6) + 'px; top:' + (data.top-11) + 'px;');
                scope.picked=true;
            })
        }
```

**The Ask**:  Is there a better/recommended way to do this?  I tried using ng-style in the html but this simply would not work for me (something to do with timing as far as I can tell) However, if I could make that work, it seems like it would be cleaner than ugly string concatenation.

**Disclaimer**: I'm relatively new to Angular.  I looked all over but could not find a better way to do this.

**Plunker Link**: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DqRhOS1XW1I9M4iUf4B)

Thank you in advance.